# Re-opening a closed NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-2.0, tcpclient, networkstream

Good morning,

I am in need of some advice, I am using a networkStream, which is streaming from a TcpClient, all was working fine, but then I required the some functionality elsewhere, which requires the stream to be closed. I can't seem to find a way to re open the connection once it has been closed. Could anyone point me in the correct direction here?

Here's an example of the code I am based on: (Obviously this isn't exactly how it works, but I've simplified it as much as possible :-))

```
private void MyMainFunction()
  {
  ConnectToTcp();

  if(CheckConnection == true)
    {
    DoWorkWithTcp();
    }

  DisconnectFromTcp();

  ConnectViaOtherSource();
  DoOtherSourceWork();
  DisconnectOtherSource();

  ConnectToTcp(); //Excecption thrown, epic fail!
  }

private void ConnectToTcp()
  {
  myClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);
  myNetStream = myClient.GetStream();
  }

private void DisconnectFromTcp()
  {
  myNetStream.Close();
  myClient.Close();
  }
```

Thanks in advance, appreciated.

**Edit - Changed variable spelling name! Whoops!**
**Edit - Sorry, just realised the problem was coming from elsewhere, thanks for confirming that this code is correct :-) Helped me spot the problem from another source**

Comment: what exception is thrown when you attempt to reconnect?

Comment: ObjectDisposedException, but I'm re-creating them?

Comment: Can you create a short, but complete, program that demonstrates the problem? Ie. something we can paste in its entirety into a console Program.cs file, compile, and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question comes up why you have to close the connection at all, can't you keep it open (dormant) during DoOtherSourceWork() ?

Apart from that, the code looks OK, creating a new TcpClient etc, so I think it depends on the other side - what does the peer software do when you close the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure since you didnt paste the whole thing but

myClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);
  myNetStream = sockClient.GetStream();

sockClient is not myClient is this a typo or its actually in the code? if thats the case you need to recreate sockClient aswell